# Finding the matrix of $f$ in the base $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

**Problem**. Let $V = {\vec{v_1} = (5, 3, 1), \vec{v_2}= (1, −3, −2), \vec{v_3} = (1, 2, 1)}$ base of $\mathbb{R^3}$ and let $f$ be the linear operator on $\mathbb{R^3}$ defined
by $f(\vec{v_1}) = (−2, 1, 0)$, $f(\vec{v_2}) = (−1, 3, 0)$, $f(\vec{v_3}) = (−2, −3, 0)$. Calculate the matrix of $f$ in the base $V$;

**How I was taught the lesson**. Now the issue is that in my book and all of my notes they always define the matrices of change of base in this way: $$y'=F_v x'$$ for the matrix $F_v$ of $f$ in a base $V$ and the matrix $P$ to change basis from the canonical to the base $V$: $$x'=Px$$ (I'm using ' for the base $V$ and no ' for the canonical).

**How I approached the problem**. So I continued doing the problem: $$x'=Px\Rightarrow x=P^{-1} x'$$ since we were given the $y'$ in terms of $x$ (the canonical base) because $f(\vec{v_1})=-2\vec{e_1}+\vec{e_2}$, $f(\vec{v_2})=-\vec{e_1}+2\vec{e_2}$ and $f(\vec{v_3})=-2\vec{e_1}-3\vec{e_2}$, we have found that matrix $M$ such that $y'=Mx$, so then: $$y'=Mx=M(P^{-1}x')=MP^{-1}x'=F_v x'$$ which I found the solution to be $F_v=MP^{-1}$ but my book now says it is $P^{-1}M$, how is that possible?

**The way they approached the problem**. The same was as I did, but instead of $y'=Mx$ they did $y'=xM$, and likewise with $x'=xP$ changing the order of the matrix and putting it in the right? And they arrive to $F_v=P^{-1}M$.

**My doubt**. *What happened? Have I done something wrong or is it just that both answers are valid? And why did they put the matrix on the right and not on the left, does it not matter as long as you are consistent with it?*

Comment: Change of basis rule is $x_{old}=Px_{new}$...

Comment: @BobDobbs sure, then we have $x=Px'$ instead of $x'=Px$, don't we? Which ends up giving us the matrix $MP$ which isn't close to the solution. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Yes: $y=Mx'$...

Comment: @BobDobbs can you pretty please expand on why $y=Mx'$ is true? It shocks me how that is true, since at no moment we have $f(\vec{e_i})$ in terms of $\vec{v_j}$

Comment: $f(\vec e_i)$s are not given. Forget $e_i$s on the left hand side, i.e. the domain.

Comment: @BobDobbs I know they are not given, I said it in my previous comment. I'm still looking for the answer of "if we don't have $f(\vec{e_i})$ in terms of $v_j$ why would I write $y=Mx$' ", it would mean a lot and would end all this thing

Comment: $y'=Fx'\implies Py'=PFx'\implies y=PFx'$

Comment: @BobDobbs once again, that *still* doesn't answer at all my question, if you could **please** answer: "if we don't have $\vec{f(e_i)}$ in terms of $\vec{vj}$ why would I write $y=Mx$' ", it's all I'm asking for, the *intuition behind it*, so that I can understand *why*, I already *know* that doing that is the way to solve it but I'm looking for your initial reasoning that made **you** write that equation.

Comment: I think you want a diagram or something like that... Let me think about it.

Comment: @BobDobbs I mean sure, but it's a really simple question, is it a too hard question to answer with words? I thought there was a simple reason

Comment: The first thing to do if you're confused about left vs right multiplication of matrices is _check if the other order is defined_. If $x$ is a vector and $M$ is $3 \times 3$, then $Mx$ is only defined if $x$ is $3 \times 1$, and $xM$ is only defined if $x$ is $1 \times 3$. So the confusion comes from you using column vectors, but your book uses row vectors

Comment: @math54321 so you are saying my solution is correct but just my 'method' uses column vectors, while my book uses row vectors?

Comment: Yes exactly $\hspace{0cm}$

Comment: @math54321 wait but rethinking it now, I'm still wondering why using $x'=Px$ was correct if the rule is $x_{old}=Px_{new}$, isn't it? And sorry for this, I just want to be crystal clear.

Comment: That rule also depends on whether you use row or column vectors. With column vectors you want to multiply the matrix on the left (i.e. $(n \times n)(n \times 1) = (n \times 1)$), and with row vectors you want to multiply the matrix on the right ($(1 \times n)(n \times n) = (1 \times n)$)

Comment: @math54321 so the rule with columns vectors is $x_{new}=Px_{old}$?

Comment: Yes, $x_{new} = Px_{old}$ is the standard equation, and is also the only reasonable one - normally the transformation goes _from_ old _to_ new. Of course if $P$ is invertible you can say $x_{old} = Px_{new} \iff P^{-1}x_{old} = x_{new}$, so you should also be careful not to mix up $P$ with $P^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
V @>F>> V\\
@V P V V  \huge\searrow\small M   @VV P V\\
\Bbb R^3 @>>\phi> \Bbb R^3
\end{CD}

$x:$ Old coordinates in domain, $y:$ Old coordinates in co-domain, $x':$ New coordinates in domain, $y':$ New coordinates in co-domain.

We have
$$y'=Fx'\tag1$$
where $F$ is the transformation matrix of the given transformation $\phi$ in the new coordinates. We want to find $F$.

[Remember that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) old coordinates and new coordinates are connected via transition matrix $P$ in the following way: $x=Px'$ in the domain and
$$y=Py'\tag2$$
in the co-domain, where $\large P=[v_1|v_2|v_3]$ is the transition matrix.

On the other hand we have
$$y=Mx'\tag3$$
where $\large M=[f(v_1)|f(v_2)|f(v_3)]$ is the tranformation matrix of the same transformation with new coordinates in the domain but old coordinates in the co-domain.

From $(2)$ and $(3)$, $y'=P^{-1}Mx'$. From $(1)$ and this, we have $Fx'=P^{-1}Mx'.$ Therefore $F=P^{-1}M$.

OP's Example: $P=\left[\begin{matrix}5&1&1\\3&-3&2\\1&-2&1\end{matrix}\right]$ and $M=\left[\begin{matrix}-2&-1&-2\\1&3&-3\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$. With some help of computer, we find $$F=P^{-1}M=\left[\begin{matrix}-5&-10&7\\6&13&-10\\17&36&-27\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: how have you gotten $y=Mx'$ and not $y'=Mx$? That is the sole purpose of the post, understand what I have gone wrong, and in my opinion, we have the $f(\vec{v_i})$ in terms of $\vec{e_j}$ which means $y'=Mx$ according to the notation we said?

Comment: We may also try writing $f(v_i)$s in terms of $v_i$s.

Comment: what do you mean by that? Can you please expand I'm pretty lost

Comment: For example, $(-2,1,0)=-5(5,3,1)+6(1,-3,-2)+17(1,2,1)$ explains the first column of $F$. Similarly, we can find the other columns without so much theory or notation which is good, I think. Not sure.

Comment: I'm really trying to understand you but I don't know how what you are saying is related with the point of my question which is understanding where my solution *went* wrong, I would appreciate if you answered me the very first commend I wrote on your post about $y=Mx'$ firstly

Comment: $y=Mx'$ because the output vectors $f(v_i)$s are written in terms of $e_i$s which are old basis.

Comment: how does that make any sense I'm so lost. It doesn't get into my brain how you can have $y=Mx'$ even though you *don't* have $f(\vec{e_i})$ in terms of $v_j$

Answer (score 4):

This can be a bit tricky, but the key is to think about which basis the coordinates are represented in. The wording of the question asks to

> Calculate the matrix of $f$ in the base $V$

This means we want a matrix $A$ such that when $w_V$ are the coordinates of a vector $w$ with respect to basis $V$, then $A w_V$ are the coordinates of $f (w)$ with respect to basis $V$. Note that I use the subscript $V$ to denote *coordinates* (or *representation*) of a vector with respect to a basis.

We know that $f$ maps the vector with coordinates $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}_V$ to the vector $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, the vector with coordinates $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}_V$ to the vector $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and the vector with coordinates $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}_V$ $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Therefore, given $w_V$, the vector

$$f (w) = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 3 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} w_V$$

is the vector output by the linear function $f$. However, we want the coordinates of this with respect to the basis $V$, which means we must apply the inverse coordinate transformation $P^{-1}$, where $P = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{pmatrix}$ is a matrix with the basis vectors of $V$ as columns.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer to the problem, but I'm still confused about *my method* and the *my doubt* section I wrote. If you could read that and help me I'd appreciate it

Comment: Your method is not correct because you assumed that $x$ was given, when in fact $x'$ (coordinates w.r.t. $V$) is given. There's no need to transform back into the canonical basis before applying $f$. However, you want the result w.r.t. $V$ (not the canonical basis), so after multiplying by $M$, you need to (left) multiply by $P^{-1}$ to get those coordinates.

Comment: oh. But how have I got $x$ and not $x'$? Since I got $f(\vec{v_1}),f(\vec{v_2}), f(\vec{v_3})$ in terms of $e_1,e_2$ and $e_3$? That's the sole reason I wrote $y'=Mx$ and $x'=Px$.

Comment: The images $f(v_i)$ are given with respect to $e_j$, yes. But you want them with respect to $v_j$, which is why $P^{-1}$ is multiplied to the left after $M$ is applied.